# My list is empty when i print it out of for in range

Tags: python, tkinter, for-in-loop

help me with this code, i do looping on entry on entries but when i print list entries out of its loop it's only show me !enties01 why it cant print me a list?

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

entries = []
wawaw=[1,2,3]
for i in range(10):

    en = Entry(root)
    en.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
    entries.append(en)



def hallo():
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.get())


    print(entries) # this only printing !enty01

button=Button(root,text="krijg",command=hallo).grid(row=12,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Has the user entered any text in all the entries?

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print(*entries, sep = ", ")
```

The * is used to print print list items in a single line separated by the value of sep (in this case a comma and space).

Comment: [GeeksForGeeks link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-lists-in-python-4-different-ways/) Method 2 is printing a list without using a loop. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from tkinter import *
    
    root=Tk()
    
    entries = []
    wawaw=[1,2,3]
    for i in range(10):
    
        en = Entry(root)
        en.grid(row=i+1, column=0)
        entries.append(en)
    
    
    
    def hallo():
        for entry in entries:
            print(entry.get())
    
    
    print(entries) # this only printing !enty01
    
    button=Button(root,text="krijg",command=hallo).grid(row=12,column=0)
    
    root.mainloop()
```